# How to pass many params to rust actix_web route

Tags: rust, actix-web

Is possible to pass more than one parameter into axtic_web route ?

```
// srv.rs (frag.)

HttpServer::new(|| {
  App::new()
    .route(
      "/api/ext/{name}/set/config/{id}",
      web::get().to(api::router::setExtConfig),
    )
})
.start();
```

```
// router.rs (frag.)

pub fn setExtConfig(
    name: web::Path<String>,
    id: web::Path<String>,
    _req: HttpRequest,
) -> HttpResponse {
  println!("{} {}", name, id);
  HttpResponse::Ok()
      .content_type("text/html")
      .body("OK")
}
```

For routes with one param everything is ok, but for this example 
i see only message in the browser: `wrong number of parameters: 2 expected 1`, and the response stauts code is 404.

I realy need to pass more parameters (from one to three or four)...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is a perfect fit for [tuple](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.tuple.html):

```
pub fn setExtConfig(
    param: web::Path<(String, String)>,
    _req: HttpRequest,
) -> HttpResponse {
    println!("{} {}", param.0, param.1);
    HttpResponse::Ok().content_type("text/html").body("OK")
}
```

Comment: It looks exelent but it couses compilation error `expected struct 'actix_web::types::path::Path', found tuple`

Comment: @PiotrPłaczek let (param1, param2) = param.into_inner();

Comment: Tupple applicable in axum as well.